# For each ordinal $\alpha$, $\alpha\le \aleph_{\alpha}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

This property is mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

I cannot find a contradiction assuming otherwise. Maybe this is proved by transfinite induction?

> $\aleph_\alpha$ is defined to be the least infinite cardinal not in $\{\aleph_\beta\}_{\beta\in\alpha}$.

---

**Edit** The useful hint that allowed me to see the proof is the *order-preserving* injection from $\alpha$ to $\aleph_\alpha$. To explain, for future viewers, recall the following fact

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $A\subseteq B$. Let $\prec_B$ be a well-order in $B$. If $\alpha$ is the ordinal of $(A,\prec_B^\ast)$ and $\beta$ is the ordinal of $(B,\prec_B)$, then $\alpha\le \beta$.

The *order-preserving* injection $f:\beta\mapsto \aleph_\beta$ (domain $\alpha$) makes the range (w/ ordinal $\alpha$) a subset of $\aleph_\alpha$ (w/ ordinal itself). Therefore $\alpha\le\aleph_\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find an injective function from $\alpha$ to $\aleph_{\alpha}$

Comment: Wouldn't that only show that $|\alpha|\le \aleph_\alpha$?

Comment: @AlbertoTakase: Yes. However an injective _order-preserving_ function $\alpha\to\omega_\alpha$ would do, if you have a good selection of lemmas about ordinals available.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  I am missing the point of the comment.  All the $\aleph$s are distinct and all are $\le \aleph_\alpha$

Comment: @RossMillikan That the injection is order preserving is what matters here. There is an injection from $\omega^3+7$ into $\omega$, which does not mean that $\omega^3+7$ precedes $\omega$ as ordinals.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Because of the $\aleph$ I was thinking cardinal comparison, so $\alpha \le \aleph_\alpha \equiv |\alpha| \le \aleph_\alpha$.  If the $\le$ is ordinal I understand.

Comment: Ross, take some $\alpha$ such that $\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$, then $\alpha+1$ has an injection into $\aleph_\alpha$.